# Uploading ProGuard Mapping Files to Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

Am trying out the recently released feature that allows uploading of ProGuard mapping file to Firebase (https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/android) using gradle task.  The following is the task I'm running.

```
./gradlew -PFirebaseServiceAccountFilePath=xxxxx.json :app:firebaseUploadReleaseProguardMapping
```

However, it doesn't seem to be recognizing service account file.  Has anyone had any luck getting this working?  I've also tried defining `FirebaseServiceAccountFilePath` in gradle.properties.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:firebaseUploadReleaseProguardMapping'.
> Service account file path has not been defined! Service accounts are used to authorize your mapping file uploads.  Learn more at
  https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/android.
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Set relative path to json in gradle.properties (in project root)

```
FirebaseServiceAccountFilePath = /firebase-crashreporting.json
```

and update this property in your build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-crash'

android {
    ...
}

setProperty("FirebaseServiceAccountFilePath", rootProject.rootDir.absolutePath + FirebaseServiceAccountFilePath)

dependencies {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Should be the accepted answer since it's more elegant than specifying the explicit, non relative path

Answer (score 5):

The error message is misleading.  You will see that if the file path that you give for the service account wasn't found.  Try passing the full, unambiguous path of the service account file (try not to depend on relative paths).

I'll make sure that the next version of the plugin has a more meaningful error message for the case where the file isn't found.  Sorry about the trouble.

Comment: Thanks Doug.  Using full path got me past that issue.  The next error I'm getting is FileNotFoundException: <my_path>/google-services.json".  I guess it makes sense that there'd be dependency on `google-services.json` (for various reasons we're using `FirebaseApp.initializeApp()` to init firebase rather than depending on existence of that file)

Comment: Got it.  That's a completely different problem.  I'll have to file a different issue to let you pass the project id through the command line as well.  For now, you could try to download your project's google-services.json file and put it in the expected place just so the plugin can get a hold of what it needs in order to perform the upload.

Comment: The issue we have with doing that is that same code/build is used to build a (dynamic) number of different apps.

Comment: Ah, yeah, I was just writing that case into the bug report. but yeah, my proposed workaround won't be easy for you, as you'd have to copy a new file into place for each variant, and run them all individually.

Comment: For what it is worth, I used a relative path. Relative to the `app` module directory and not the project directory.

Comment: This is a great feature, I introduced this to my team a while back and was very jealous of the fact that iOS symbols were uploaded automatically and we would have to upload them manually :) but I would love to be able to use a relative path for the service account file, we have multiple release managers and having each one of them define the file path differently would be a hassle.

Comment: @DougStevenson I'm also getting FileNotFoundException (since i have different google.json for debug and release). I understand your proposed solution, but is this solved yet? Can I pass google.json as an argument in console?

Comment: @DougStevenson  what specific fields in `google-services.json` does the plugin need access to (thinking in the case I described above where there's multiple apps.....if perhaps we can dynamically update that particular field in the file before running the task)?

Comment: @JohnO'Reilly You should be able to figure out what you need from this documentation: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin  The contents of the final resources are what matter the most.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using Jenkins to upload the proguard mappings for me. I had to change the file permissions for the json private key file from `400` to `444`.