# Uploading ProGuard Mapping Files to Firebase from Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, mapping, android-proguard

I'm sorry if i repeat the question, but i'm having difficulties in uploading mapping file to firebase account after release. I have read official documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/android , which is very difficult and not clear (may be because, i'm using only firebase crash report and did not read whole documentation of firebase)
Moreover i went through following links
[Uploading ProGuard Mapping Files to Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41198758/uploading-proguard-mapping-files-to-firebase) and 
[Uploading ProGuard Mapping Files to Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41198758/uploading-proguard-mapping-files-to-firebase)
and added 
FirebaseServiceAccountFilePath = D:\Workspace\AndroidStudio\DiscountApp\crashreporting.json property to gradle.properties file. But when i put cursor on it, the hint shows "Unused property"
I also added 
setProperty("FirebaseServiceAccountFilePath", "D:\Workspace\AndroidStudio\DiscountApp\crashreporting.json") 
to build.gradle after releasing signed apk and uploading it play store account, in firebase account nothing changed. I still have to wait for the first error to upload mapping files.
So please provide step by step instructions with exact commands to do this.
Thank you for attention.

Comment: are you trying to automate or uploading it manually ??

Comment: at the moment i upload manually, but  want to do it automaticlly.