# Error to upload mapping proguard file to Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, android-proguard

This [configuration](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/android) was complete but, during execute the command:

```
./gradlew :app:firebaseUploadReleaseProguardMapping
```

An error occur:

> Configuration 'compile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use
>   'implementation' instead. registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use
>   registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection) registerResGeneratingTask is
>   deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
>   registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use
>   registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection) registerResGeneratingTask is
>   deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
>   registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use
>   registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection) registerResGeneratingTask is
>   deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
>   registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use
>   registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection) registerResGeneratingTask is
>   deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
>
> - Exception is: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:firebaseUploadPrdReleaseProguardMapping'.
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
>         at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
>         at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
>         at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
>     Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Unable to upload mapping
>     file. 
>         at com.google.firebase.crash.plugin.NetworkConnectionProvider.getSignedUrlKey(NetworkConnectionProvider.java:44)
>         at com.google.firebase.crash.plugin.SingleVersionMappingFileUploader.uploadMappingFile(SingleVersionMappingFileUploader.java:49)
>         at com.google.firebase.crash.plugin.MultiVersionMappingFileUploader.upload(MultiVersionMappingFileUploader.java:22)
>         at com.google.firebase.crash.plugin.UploadProguardMappingTask.uploadMappingFile(UploadProguardMappingTask.java:197)
>         at com.google.firebase.crash.plugin.UploadProguardMappingTask.parseGoogleServicesFile(UploadProguardMappingTask.java:181)
>         at com.google.firebase.crash.plugin.UploadProguardMappingTask.action(UploadProguardMappingTask.java:104)
>         at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:46)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:784)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:751)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
>         ... 29 more Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error reading credentials from stream, 'type' field not specified.
>         at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.fromStream(GoogleCredential.java:254)
>         at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.fromStream(GoogleCredential.java:226)
>         at com.google.firebase.crash.plugin.NetworkConnectionProvider.newHttpRequestFactory(NetworkConnectionProvider.java:87)
>         at com.google.firebase.crash.plugin.NetworkConnectionProvider.getSignedUrlKey(NetworkConnectionProvider.java:39)
>         ... 47 more

The path with google-services.json was configured in the gradle.properties and I have the install Java 8 because this [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46917365/error-could-not-initialize-class-com-android-sdklib-repository-androidsdkhandle?rq=1) .

Answer (score 0):

Judging from `Error reading credentials from stream, 'type' field not specified` error it looks like issue with your service account file:

Make sure you've created service account/private key, downloaded associated service account file and pointed to it using `FirebaseServiceAccountFilePath` property (as per firebase.google.com/docs/crash/android )

Following has some more info on setting of that property [Uploading ProGuard Mapping Files to Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41198758/uploading-proguard-mapping-files-to-firebase)

Comment: It's stranger because, json file was downloaded from Google Firebase console. I generate another and problem persists.

Comment: Does the package name of your app and that in `google-services.json` match?

Comment: The package is ok.